# Modules with the same name in two different Ruby files

Tags: ruby

My "file 1"

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\page-object-0.9.2\lib\page-object.rb
```

and my directory

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\page-object-0.9.2\lib\page-object
```

are located on my hard drive as a consequence of page-object gem installation.

In the contents of "file 1", among the other lines of code, I see the following line:

```
require 'page-object/page_populator'
```

Lower in the same file, I see:

```
module PageObject
  include PagePopulator
```

Looking at "file 2"

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\page-object-0.9.2\lib\page-object\page_populator.rb
```

these lines are at the top of this file:

```
module PageObject
  module PagePopulator
```

Based on the Ruby tutorials that I read, that say that after requiring "file 2" into "file 1" using `require`, modules from "file 2" need to be included into the "file 1" with `include`.

I would expect "file 1" to have

```
include PageObject::PagePopulator
```

instead of

```
include PagePopulator
```

However, since it is not setup this way, and page-object is a widely-used gem, I believe that having the `PageObject` module in both files eliminates the need for

```
include PageObject::PagePopulator
```

because

```
include PagePopulator
```

is sufficient.

I wanted to confirm that my assumption is right.

Having read about Module.nesting method and also having read the links returned by googling "reopening classes/modules" query, I still didn't find the answer to my question.

I will try to describe it again.

content of file_a is below:

```
require "file_b"
 module Foo
  include Bar
    ...
end
```

content of file_b is below:

```
module Foo
 module Bar
   ...
end
```

Where is the explanation that we shouldn't use 
in file_a the following:

```
include Foo::Bar
```

instead of

```
include Bar
```

and the way I have written it before:

```
include Bar
```

is sufficient

What would be the difference if we have

file_c  with the following content:

```
module Bar
    ...
end
```

Does it mean that there is no difference in including module from this file_c versus file_b?

content of file_a with module from file_b and module from file_c is below:

```
require "file_b"
 require "file_c"
  module Foo
   include Bar
     ...
  end
```

If this is the case what is the point of having module Foo in file_b?

Comment: Your file1 is the same as file2

Comment: Why on earth would you expect `include PagePopulator::PageObject`?

Comment: Sergio - sorry - I corrected this

Comment: You may want use github links to those two source files:  https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_populator.rb   and https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object.rb

Comment: To answer your question:
"Why on earth would you expect include PagePopulator::PageObject?"
Can you show at least one Ruby tutorial saying that if you have same module defined in 2 different files you don't have to add it in the include statement?

Comment: I mean, why `include PagePopulator::PageObject` and not `include PageObject::PagePopulator`?

Comment: In short, the concept you're confused with here is called "reopening classes/modules". You can google it.

Comment: I haven't found any source that is saying that having 2 modules with the same name in 2 different files, and requiring one file from the other offsets their modules.

Comment: Sergio - there is a typo in my description should be

Comment: include PageObject::PagePopulator

Comment: instead of  
include PagePopulator::PageObject
I corrected this in description

Comment: Point of interest, what do you use `page-object` gem for? :)

Comment: PageObject gem is used in Ruby/Cucumber framework for regression testing of the web applications. It eases a lot interaction with the web page - see comments in page-object.rb. Also book mentioned here is a good resource http://www.cheezyworld.com/cucumber-cheese/

Comment: Frederick from Answer 1 was right - I used this gem as example of same name module interactions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to ask about is the rules for constant lookup in ruby: when you write `Bar` in your code, how does ruby find the value of that constant?

What files things are in is irrelevant, what matters is that within

```
module Foo
  ...
end
```

A reference to `Bar` will try `Foo::Bar` and then the top level `::Bar` constant ( constant scoping is lexically scoped)

So in the case where `Foo::Bar` has been previously defined then

```
module Foo
  include Foo::Bar
end
```

And

```
module Foo
  include Bar
end
```

Do the same thing.

The `Module.nesting` method will show you this lookup chain. Ruby will also search the ancestors of the currently open class / module. There are some gotchas / corner cases, but those are the basics.

Comment: I am not sure that you are answering what I asked, or maybe I didn't understand the answer.  

     file_a
    require "file_b"
    module Foo
       include Bar
       ...
    end

file_b:
module Foo
  module Bar
...
end

Where is the explanation that 
include Foo::Bar
does not need to be used in file_a

I am looking currently at Module.nesting assuming that is will give me the answer
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting

Comment: I think you explained general rule about nesting, and example on the 
ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting
page shows how to find out nested modules/constants.
I updated my initial post with more descriptive details